Didactic tool to play with deterministic and nondeterministic automata
I'm looking for some tool, either online or not, to let students play with automata.
What I'm looking for specifically is for a tool that allows one to build an automaton and construct its powerset and then its minimal DFA.
I've found this tool online: https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/min_dfa
It is actually good when you start from a regular expression, but it does not let you play with the automaton and e.g. change some transitions or add/remove states and see how the minimal DFA changes.
Is there any tool like this around?

Perhaps it would be more on-topic on [cseducators.se]?

Didn’t know about that site! Thanks!

Not sure about its exact features but check out flaci.com

Sounds cool, but please tell me there’s an English version!
